# Как избежать деления в знаменателе?

Tags: c, математика

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    float x1,x2,x3,y1,y2,y3;
    float a, b;
    int s;
    do {    
        printf ("Введите координаты первой точки: ");
         scanf ("%f %f", &x1, &y1);
         printf ("Введите координаты второй точки: ");
         scanf ("%f %f", &x2, &y2);
        printf ("Введите координаты третей точки: ");
        scanf ("%f %f", &x3, &y3);
        printf ("\n");
    }  
while ((x1 == x2 || x1 == x3 || x2 == x1 || x2 == x3 || x3 == x1 || x3 == x2 ) && (y1 == y2 || y1 == y3 || y2 == y1 || y2 == y3 || y3 == y1 || y3 == y2));
if (x1 == x2) {
    if (x1 == x3) printf ("Данные точки лежат на одной прямой.\n");
    else printf ("Данные точки не лежат на одной прямой.\n");
}
else a = (y1-y2)/(x1-x2);
b = y1 - a * x1;
if (a * x3 + b == y3) printf ("Данные точки лежат на одной прямой.\n");
else printf ("Данные точки не лежат на одной прямой.\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Деления в знаменателе у Вас в коде нет. Избегать ничего не надо.

Comment: Что это за ужОс: `(x1 == x2 || x1 == x3 || x2 == x1 || x2 == x3 || x3 == x1 || x3 == x2 )` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

чтобы избавиться от деления, нужно все члены уравнения умножить на знаменатель (логику не проверял)

```
else 
  a = (y1-y2);
  b = (y1 - a * x1) * (x1-x2);
  if (a * x3 + b == y3 * (x1-x2))
```

Это должно быть эквивалентно косому произведению векторов (dx13 = x3-x1 и т.д.)

```
dx13 * dy12 - dx12 * dy13 = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

> Как избежать деления ?

Очень просто: не заниматься такой ерундой, как использование уравнения прямой вида `y = ax + b` для решения данной задачи.

Либо стройте общее уравнение прямой вида `Ax + By + C = 0`.

Либо вообще абстрагируйтесь от явного построения уравнения прямой, а вместо этого просто посчитайте площадь треугольника, образованного данными точками.

Никакого деления в этих элементарных способах решения данной задачи нет и в помине.

Ну и отдельно стоит заметить, что в рамках данной задачи попытки сравнения плавающих значений на точное равенство ни к чему хорошему не приведут.

Answer (score 0):

Ну просто выполните простейшие выкладки...

Если не ошибаюсь -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]